# add text area on selecting options in dropdown list in java script

Tags: javascript, css, list, dropdown, onselect

```js
function showInsertQuest(){
    var x = document.getElementById("one");
    if (x.style.display === "none"){
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}


const target = document.querySelector("#second");

const displayWhenSelected = (source, value, target) => {
    const selectedIndex = source.selectedIndex;
    const isSelected = source[selectedIndex].value === value;
    target.classList[isSelected
        ? "add"
        : "remove"
    ]("show");
};
if(source= document.querySelector("#location"))
source.addEventListener("change", (evt) =>
    displayWhenSelected(source, "loc5", target)
);
```

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
}
#container {
  border: 4px solid;
  position: auto;
  height: 650;
  width: 700px;
}
.main {
  border-bottom: solid;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
h2 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  color: darkcyan;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
}
#bottom {
  border-top: 0.7solid;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
button {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  color: white;
  height: 35px;
  width: 80px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}

/* Insert Button */

.insert-btn {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 480px;
  color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 510.53px;
  border-top: none;
  height: 40px;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
}


.insert-btn:hover {
  background: grey;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow);
  color: white;
}

.insert-btn:active {
  background: grey;
  color: black;
  border: transparent;
}

#one {
  width: 700px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}

#one input {
  width: 0px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 500px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: grey;
}

#one #Multiplechoice {
  margin-right: 0px;
  display: inline;
  border: none;
  position: fixed;
  height: 19px;
}

i {
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  color: grey;
}
#one .on {
  padding-left: 9px;
}

#one #second {
  margin-left: 22px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: none;
}
#one #second .show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="main">
        <h2>ADD NEW CALL</h2>
    </div> 
       
    <section class="insert-quest" id="insertquestone">
        <div id="one" >
            <div class="on">
                1 <input type="text"/><i class="fa fa-adn" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                <!-- DROPDOWN -->
                <select id="location" name="drop">
                    <option value="Select">Select</option>
                    <option value="loc5" >Multi-line text</option>
                    <option value="loc6" >Single choice</option>
                    <option value="loc7">Multi choice</option>      
                </select>
            </div>
            <!-- TEXTAREA -->
            <textarea name="term" id="second" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>        
       </div>
   </section>

    <div id="content">

        <!-- Insert Quest Button -->
        <input type="button" value="+ADD NEW QUESTION" class="insert-btn" id="insertbtn" onclick="showInsertQuest()"/>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        <h3><button>SAVE</button> cancel </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** I modified codes in your question for better readability @Adam P.

trying to get a text area on selecting multi line text from drop down list
SIMAILARLY on selecting single choice add 1 text box below the question
and on selecting single choice add 5 text box below the question...

getting error of Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Is the DOM loaded when you use `querySelector`?

Comment: Hi Shubh. Please improve your question, by applying the concepts described here [ask]. Not YELLING is an appreciated style. Providing more info, explanation, details of your own thoughts, results of your own debugging attempts and analysis experiments would very much help with providing help to you. Also, many users appreciate questions by users which did at least spend the effort of taking the [tour], to show willingness of understanding and embracing the concepts of this community. Doing that would also have avoided the system requirement to show more non-code with your rather large code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make textarea visible, you'll have to do several things:

in JS part, change

```
if(source= document.querySelector("#location"))
```

to

```
const source = document.querySelector("#location");
```

This change is pretty self-explanatory, you need to define node when you attach eventListener.

In CSS change:

```
#one #second {
  margin-left: 22px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: none;
}
#one #second .show {
  display: block;
}
```

to

```
#second {
  margin-left: 22px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: none;
}
#second.show {
  display: block;
}
```

You don't need #one selector, one `id` selector is enough. Also, when you add a class (`.show`) to an element that already has `id` defined, you need to write that class without a space between id name and class name in CSS.

**EDIT**: You are probably loading your script in `<head>` tag. This way, script cannot attach eventListener, because DOM element is not available yet. To fix this and remove `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` error, you need to load your script right before ending of `</body>`, like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...content of your web page
        <script></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i did as you said but the error " Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null "

Comment: I added the solution in EDIT part of the comment

Comment: wooooohhhhh..... it works totally fine now... thank you